# Control + Shift + 3 generates "Can't override a Firefox shortcut" error in Multi-Account Containers

Tags: macos, firefox-addon, shortcut

control-shift-3

and

control-shift-6

generate a pop-up message "Can't override a Firefox shortcut" in Manage Extension Shortcuts
page of the Firefox **Multi-Account Containers extension** (macOS Ventura 13.0, firefox 114.0.2).
It is not possible to set the above shortcuts to open a given container type.

Also, I cannot find anywhere on the internet what these shortcuts do in Firefox. When I use them, nothing happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Manjaro Linux with Firefox 115.0.1 (64-bit), so it appears to be macOS-specific (but I haven't tried it on Windows 10 yet). On my system, the default "Container Shortcut 3" is Ctrl-Shift-3, and the default "Container Shortcut 6" is Ctrl-Shift-6. What are they on your system?

Comment: @ThomasMueller The default shortcuts are Command-Shift-3 and Command-Shift-6 respectively. In general, the default shortcuts are Command-Shift-<digit> for each 1-9 container. 
However Command-Shift-3 for "Container Shortcut 3" and Command-Shift-4 for "Container Shortcut 4" do not work, as they are intercepted by the macOS system's default shortcuts for capturing screenshots. 
I have tried to redefine these shortcuts to Control-Shift-<digit> (inspired by a youtube tutorial), but as described in the pb, number 3 and 6 don't work for some reason.

Comment: When you try to change the shortcut by pressing (and holding) Ctrl-Shift-3, does Firefox actually display "Ctrl-Shift-3" in the "type a shortcut" field? If it does, then I'm out of ideas, and you should probably ask on https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/add-ons/35

Comment: @ThomasMueller Yes, it does. I may go through various discussions relating to addon shortcuts on discourse.mozzilla.org at a later time. Thank you for the tips.